# Inner joining tables A and B returns 50 rows. Left join B to A returns 125 rows. What's going on here?

Tags: sql, join

Inner joining tables A and B returns 50 rows. Left join B to A returns 125 rows. What's going on here?

Comment: I think you haven't read carefully about how `inner join` and `left join` work

Comment: Inner join retunr only the maching rows  .. left join return also the not matching rows ..  you should study the join more deeply

Answer (score 2):

Left join can be bigger than inner join, and contain the same data + more data from table A.

Look at the following chart for reference:
[image]